# how do i refresh my vs code changes into the browser

Tags: firefox, browser, settings, vscode-extensions

in my desktop, i already have installed live server on auto save mode (afterDelay) and it works perfectly fine, after i save my changes(CTRL + S) they refresh immediately in my browser

however in my laptop despite having the same configuration in settings for autosave(afterDelay), it does NOT refresh, i already unninstalled VS CODE and extentions and still cannot make it work.
to check changes in my code i have to refresh the browser, however is a little bit tedious because i get my default page and i have to start over to check how the page is working in certain sections

if i compare my "settings.json" from one computer to another they are different

the computer that is working fine in the refreser has the next configuration:

```
{
    "editor.fontSize": 16,
    "editor.formatOnPaste": true,
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.wordWrap": "on",
    "json.schemas": [
    
    ]
}
```

the one that is not working the refreshing has the next configuration:

```
{  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "files.autoSaveDelay": 1,
  "[html]": { 
   "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
},
"[jsonc]": {
"editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode" 
},
"python.testing.autoTestDiscoverOnSaveEnabled": false,
"liveServer.settings.useWebExt": true, 
"json.schemas": [  

  
  ], 
"liveServer.settings.AdvanceCustomBrowserCmdLine": "", 
"files.autoSave": "afterDelay"
}
```

i am plain begginer and i havenot found any video tutorial that could help with this issue, i hope someone can give me some advise or suggestion or even the solution for this

my general purpose browser is Mozilla so please if there is a solution for another browser i would really want to know the solution to work in Firefox as well

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about how exactly you can solve this problem, I have had the same problem many times and this solutions always work for me (setting a default browser), here is the link, hope some of this solutions work for you https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/visual-studio-code-live-server-not-working/